# Error logitech mouse software

Tags: windows-10, drivers, logitech-mouse

I recently bought a mouse, and so I installed the driver that goes with it.

But when I try to execute the program, this error (0xc000007b) appears:

```
The application did not start properly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.
```

[image: error 0xc000007b]

It tells that the application couldn't launch

The mouse I use is logitech G502, I downloaded the driver [here](http://support.logitech.com/fr_ch/product/g502-proteus-core-tunable-gaming-mouse/downloads)

I actually have the version 8.88 since I tried the three and stayed with the last one for the moment since it's still not working.

From where could that come? I have installed all the Microsoft visual C++ distributions to trying resolve that, didn't work...

Comment: Try not to install any driver manually. Just rely on the Windows pre-installed drivers.

Comment: sure but I need it to configure my mouse, it is totally working but I need the program to set the exact DPI I want for the mouse, and other stuffs like this

Comment: Many article in Google search [error 0xc000007b](https://www.google.com/search?q=0xc000007b).

Comment: I already tried a lot of those recommendations, and I executed everything proposed on this page: https://www.pingzic.com/fix-0xc00007b/ , still not working